# Illegal characters in Javascript file causing form to not work with Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, illegal-characters

Can someone please take a look at these, it just is not happing  for me its a html form, a php file to process it and a javascript file, errors in the  from browser show things like U+12AF  phantom illegal characters in the JScript file, been going at it for 1.5 hours and am at my wits end.

```
--submit.js--

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#paycheck').bind('submit', function() {
            $.post('Paycheck.php', $("#paycheck").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});

    --Paycheck.html--
    <!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <pre><title>Weekly Gross Paycheck Calculator</title></pre>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2 style = "text-align:center">PayCheck</h2>
    <form name="paycheck" id="paycheck" action="" method="POST"> 
    <p>Number of Hours: <input type="text" name="numHours"/></p> 
    <p>Hourly Wage $<input type="text" name="hourlyWage"/></p>


    <p><input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" /></p>
    </form>
<!-- Form and javascript will output the results  here -->
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>


--Paycheck.php--

<?php
function validateInput($data, $fieldName){
    global $errorCount;
    if (empty($data)) {
        echo "\"$fieldName\" is a required field.<br/>\n";
        ++$errorCount;
        $retval = "";
    } else { // Only clean up the input if it isn't empty
        if (!is_numeric($data)){
            echo "\"$fieldName\" must be numeric.<br/>\n";
            ++$errorCount;
            $retval = "";
        }else{
        $retval = trim($data);
        $retval = stripslashes($retval);
        }
    return($retval);
    } // end validateInput()
}
$ShowForm = TRUE;
$errorCount = 0;
$numHours = "";
$hourlyWage = "";
$wage = "";

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $numHours = validateInput($_POST['numHours'],"Number of Hours");
    $hourlyWage = validateInput($_POST['hourlyWage'],"Hourly Wage");
    if ($errorCount==0)
        $ShowForm = FALSE;
    else
        $ShowForm = TRUE;
}
echo $numHours ." " . $hourlyWage;
if ($ShowForm == TRUE) {
    if ($errorCount > 0)// if there were errors
        print  "<p>Please re-enter the form information below.</p>\n";
} else {
//If hours are over 40 then use time and a half
    if($numHours > 40) { $wage = ((($numHours - 40) * 1.5) * $hourlyWage) + ($hourlyWage * 40); }
//otherwise use normal multiplication.
    else { $wage = $numHours * $hourlyWage; }
    print "<p>Your weekly gross salary is $". $wage . ".</p>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're wrapping in document ready twice...

Comment: this is my first time I see `<pre>` applied to the title. Can someone tell me what it does?

Comment: @ajax333221 It does nothing lol I was trying to get it to show the code blocks in a certain way, but then I figured out the ctrl + K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

You have an extra nested lambda function in your js which is not required.

```
$(document).ready($(function() {
    $('#paycheck').bind('submit', function() {
        $.post('Paycheck.php', $("#paycheck").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

There is no action on your form, change to `action="Payment.php"`

Also in the php script line 27 should be `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` (with a lower case s in submit).

After these changes everything seems to work as intended.

Comment: What do I look for when Im seeing ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Do you have a live internet connection from your web server? (As you are loading jQuery remotely)

Comment: Your welcome to look at what I have here, I see the error when I watch the data from opera dragonfly/firebug in firefox. http://php.missioncollege.edu/~ca86_46/chapt_4/Paycheck.html

Comment: Ah, it is because your jQuery include is pointing to an expired / broken address. Use the google cdn: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: Well, as stated before, the code posted worked with no errors after changes above, and using a live jQuery library. So something must be different still...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the last line in your php script? I mean, shouldn't the dollar sign be escaped like in:

```
print "<p>Your weekly gross salary is \$". $wage . ".</p>\n";
```

Comments are right btw:

**1)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // don't double wrap
    $('#paycheck').bind('submit', function() {
        $.post('Paycheck.php', $("#paycheck").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**2)**

```
<head>
<title>Weekly Gross Paycheck Calculator</title>
<!-- no pre tags -->
<script type=...
```

Comment: Im seeing ReferenceError: data is not defined when attempting to use the jscript :|

Comment: That's probably because at the time JQuery is loaded you don't have the **#paycheck** element ready. Try using `live` instead of `bind`.